# JQuery / JavaScript won't work WITHIN AJAX script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My page uses an AJAX script that dynamically loads content into my content DIV from a separate HTML page "content.html".

The problem i am facing again and again however is that if the content contains any form of script, for instance my slideshow JQuery Plugin or my dynamic tabs plugin it simply won't work.

My site is:
http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/print.html

If you notice the image slide ticker on that page, and the tabs below the text, they are examples of JQuery that won't work when loaded into that content DIV via my AJAX script. If you click "About" on the left hand Nav bar, you'll notice the image slide show dissapears, the code exists for it to load it in, but for some reason, the combination of AJAX and any other code doesn't want to work.

For example, my AJAX code is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#about2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #about");
});

  $("#process2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #process");
});

});
```

Then within my "#about" DIV in "content.html" i have my slideshow code which is:

```
<div id="about">

<div id="slides">
<img src="images/inkedup1slide.jpg">
<img src="images/catwalk2slide.jpg">
<img src="images/teatslide.jpg">
<img src="images/infiniteslide.jpg">
<img src="images/cc2slide.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

The script for the slideshow, which isn't mine, simply a plugin is:

```
 $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 740,
        height: 100,
        navigation: {
            effect: "fade"
        },
        pagination: {
            effect: "fade"
        },
        play: {
            active: true,
            auto: true,
            interval: 4000,
            swap: true,
            effect: "fade"
        },
        effect: {
            fade: {
            speed: 800
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Plus the entire plugin script, which seems fruitless to copy into here since it's massive, and is a fully working plugin.

Can anyone help me out here? It's driving me mad.

Thanks, all the best,
Alex

Comment: Not too sure what that's supposed imply with regards to this, but thanks.

Comment: Thankyou, title changed.

Comment: Don't just dump a link here... then after you fix your website this question is absolutely useless to future readers.  You also cannot seriously expect us to dig through your code.  [Please see this link for how to ask a question:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe something like this would help:  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Apologies for not including code or anything, but it's not a specific problem, i've updated the post to include some form of relevant code, but really, i'm not sure where the issue lies, most likely in my AJAX script which is above, i doubt very much the problem is with any of the plugins i have, since they all work fine on normal pages, simply not when loaded in via AJAX.

Comment: As for the .getscript, it's not what i use, it's .load, which is a much simpler function.

Comment: Yeah, clearly you missed the point...  as you're observing, you cannot always load scripts with `.load()` and expect them to run... that's why I'm pointing you to `.getScript()`.

Comment: Carefully read the **"Script Execution"** section of this page:  https://api.jquery.com/load/ ~ Also, just above this section is, _"...browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements.  As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser."_

Comment: I see, so scripts are un-executable if loaded dynamically via .load, hence why i am now looking into .GetScript now, but it seems like a mind boggle with regards to what i am trying to achieve. I understand browsers filter certain tags, but there are no scripts attached to the actual content.html page, the scripts are all attached to the page the content is being loaded into, much like the CSS.

Comment: But the content doesn't yet exist in the DOM when those scripts are first loaded.  You always need to run those _after_ the HTML exists.

Comment: I was thinking maybe with an onclick $getscript function linked to the navigation on the left (what puts the .load into function), it'd work, but no luck there either.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Even so, attaching the scripts to the "content.html" page, i.e where the content is being 'grabbed' from, it still fails to work.

Comment: Yeah, only after i'd sent my response, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
$("#content").load("content.html #about");
```

is like the example in the **"Script Execution"** section of [the `.load()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

> *When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:*
>
> *in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into `#b` are stripped out and **not executed**:*
>
> `$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );`

---

You could try using the [jQuery `.getScript()` method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) within your `.load()` callback function.  This will ensure the new HTML is loaded before the scripts are loaded and executed.

```
$("#content").load("content.html #about", function() {
    $.getScript("myJavaScript.js");
});
```

Comment: Seems to bugger the AJAX .load to the point where it doesn't load anymore:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#about2").click(function(){
 $("#content").load("content.html #about", function() {
    $.getScript("slides.js");
});

Comment: @user3494604, and what is your error console telling you?  (Looks like all kinds of closing braces are missing from the version you pasted into the comment above.)

Comment: Yeah missing closing brackets, problem solved, your answer works perfectly, thankyou.